# Reference lists

Tags: discussion, references

Could we please collect here the topics, which ask for lists -- i.e. whose answers are a list of book recommendations or sutta recommendations.

I hope this may be useful for people who ask for book recommendations and other general references.

Answer (score 2):

- [Introductory books to Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/60/introductory-books-to-buddhism)
- [What teachings do all schools of Buddhism share?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/what-teachings-do-all-schools-of-buddhism-share)
- [Beginner academic text recommendation](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/beginner-academic-text-recommendation)
- [Why isn't there a Buddhist Bible?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/why-isnt-there-a-buddhist-bible)
- [English (or other European) translations of Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/4109/english-or-other-european-translations-of-pali-canon)
- [Chronological or other sequence for beginners](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/4112/chronological-or-other-sequence-for-beginners)
- [The Abhidamma Pitaka](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5842/the-abhidamma-pitaka)
- [Best books & articles for practicing jhanas](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/best-books-articles-for-practicing-jhanas)
- [Important readings in vipassana](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/important-readings-in-vipassana)
- [What books address various difficulties that may arise during various stages of meditation practice?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/what-books-address-various-difficulties-that-may-arise-during-various-stages-of)
- [Any advice for beginners about Vipassana traditions?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/any-advice-for-beginners-about-vipassana-traditions)
- [Looking for a book that covers the biography of the Buddha's life](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9845/looking-for-a-book-that-covers-the-biography-of-the-buddhas-life)
- [Recommendation - Book for beginner](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/12794/recommendation-book-for-beginner)
- [I would like to become Buddhist](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/14072/i-would-like-to-become-buddhist)
- [What is the best introductory (but comprehensive) book on SECULAR Buddhism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/15147/what-is-the-best-introductory-but-comprehensive-book-on-secular-buddhism)
- [Starting Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/20182/starting-buddhism)
- [Is there anything I can read about the Buddhist tradition today?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/21288/is-there-anything-i-can-read-about-the-buddhist-tradition-today)
- [Which is a good book to read about history of Buddhism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/which-is-a-good-book-to-read-about-history-of-buddhism)
- [8 Precept Commentaries?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/8-precept-commentaries)
- [Please Recommend Pure Land / Other Power Buddhism Books](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/23605/please-recommend-pure-land-other-power-buddhism-books)
- [Best study tools on the net or books](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/25432/best-study-tools-on-the-net-or-books)
- [List of book recommendations](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/25889/list-of-book-recommendations)
- [List of Buddhist podcast recommendations](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/26201/list-of-buddhist-podcast-recommendations)
- [Resources to learn about yogacara buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/33058/resources-to-learn-about-yogacara-buddhism)
- [Can anyone please list important books on Buddhism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/33802/can-anyone-please-list-important-books-on-buddhism)
- [Introductory/Beginner books on Buddhism, but for children](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/35669/introductory-beginner-books-on-buddhism-but-for-children)
- [Sources for the Whole Tipitaka](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/35960/sources-for-the-whole-tipitaka)
- [Books on meditation?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/36573/books-on-meditation)
- [Basic readings and references: where to start](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/basic-readings-and-references-where-to-start)

There's also a list of "Useful resources" at the top of [the Help page](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help)